# AUSU jquery-Ajax Autosuggest Multiple values

Tags: mysql, autosuggest

I have a form which has the following fields: 
Company Name, 
Address,
City

Using the AUSU jquery autosuggest scripts I am able to populate the address field based on the search done in the company field but what I can't seem to be able to accomplish is also populating the city field with the appropriate value. All data is stored in a mysql database.

I've gotten as far as being able to have the address and city populate the address field but I need these 2 values to go into their respective fields (shiptoaddress and shiptocity).

Any suggestions?

This is my php to obtain data from mysql database:

```
    <?php 

    $con    =   mysql_connect("localhost","userid","password");
    if (!$con){ die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); }
    mysql_select_db("dbase", $con);


    $id     =   @$_POST['id'];          // The id of the input that submitted the request.
    $data   =   @$_POST['data'];        // The value of the textbox.

 if ($id && $data)
{
    if ($id=='clients')
    {
        $query  = "SELECT shiptoaddress,company, shiptocity
                  FROM Clients
                  WHERE company LIKE '%$data%'
                  LIMIT 5";

        $result = mysql_query($query);

        $dataList = array();

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $toReturn   = $row['company'];
            $dataList[] = '<li id="' .$row['shiptoaddress'] .$row['shiptocity'] . '"><a href="#">' . htmlentities($toReturn) . '</a></li>';

        }

        if (count($dataList)>=1)
        {
            $dataOutput = join("\r\n", $dataList);
            echo $dataOutput;
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<li><a href="#">No Results</a></li>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

And this is part of the html form code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.fn.autosugguest({  
           className: 'ausu-suggest',
          methodType: 'POST',
            minChars: 2,
              rtnIDs: true,
            dataFile: 'data.php'
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
  <form action="index.php" method="get">
    <div class="ausu-suggest">
      <input type="text" size="100" value="" name="clients" id="clients" autocomplete="off" />
      <input type="text" size="100" value="" name="shiptoaddress" id="shiptoaddress" autocomplete="off"/>
      <input type="text" size="100" value="" name="shiptocity" id="shiptocity" autocomplete="off"/>


    </div>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by using the Jquery autocomplete widget.